# Show hide 5 divs at a time

Tags: jquery, html, toggle

I found this code awhile back and unfortunately I can't find who the original author is (whoever it is, THANK YOU)...

http://jsbin.com/amituh/11/

It's awesome but how can I make it so there's another button to show 3 divs less (but always at least 3 divs show). How to make it show all divs?

Thanks everyone

Comment: The source for that code http://jsbin.com/amituh/11/edit

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick note, If you're using Chrome (and Firefox does this too, I'm just not as familiar with it) you can right-click and inspect element, to see the source for the page, and the resources tab gives you access to any external scripts as well. It's really handy for learning new techniques!

Anyways, as to your question,

To remove three rows there are several approaches. Here's the route I would take, though bear in mind, there are other ways, probably even better ones.

The script you gave as an example starts with all of the lines already created, just hidden. You could do it with append/remove in jQuery to get the same effect without the limits.

Here's the functions I wrote for it, they can be included in script tags in the head:

```
window.linecount = 0;
function add3lines()
{
     $('body').append("<div id='line"+window.linecount+"'>A Line Of Text</div><br />");
     window.linecount = window.linecount+1;
     $('body').append("<div id='line"+window.linecount+"'>A Line Of Text</div><br />");
     window.linecount = window.linecount+1;
     $('body').append("<div id='line"+window.linecount+"'>A Line Of Text</div><br />");
     window.linecount = window.linecount+1;
}

function remove3lines()
{
     $(body).remove('#line'+window.linecount);
     window.linecount = window.linecount-1;
     $(body).remove('#line'+window.linecount);
     window.linecount = window.linecount-1;
     $(body).remove('#line'+window.linecount);
     window.linecount = window.linecount-1;
}
```

Then you can call your desired function from the onclick of your button or link like so:

```
<button onclick='add3lines()'>Add 3 Lines</button>
<button onclick='remove3lines()'>Remove 3 Lines</button>
```

Comment: Not quite what I'm looking for... In the finished product, I am using this with limiting Wordpress posts. Not interested in using plugins and I'm so close to figuring it out. But would be awesome if I can somehow add to my original code to lessen and show all...